Translating Russian "не то, не то" into English
The Russian language has a funny construct, "не то, не то" (roughly meaning "neither entirely/positively this, nor entirely/positively that") which normally indicates that the speaker is not entirely sure that either of the options is true (but one of them is ostensibly true).
The second quite popular way to use this construct is sarcasm.
What would be the best way to translate it into English? I've checked the existing translations and it looks like the wordplay is completely lost.
Use N1 examples:

Он не то геолог, не то археолог ~ "He's some kind of geologist or archaeologist" ("some kind" vs. implied "I'm not sure what his occupation is, could be this or could be that").

Use N2 examples:

Российская экономика совершила не то прорыв, не то рывок ~ "The Russian economy has made a breakthrough or a leap" (the implied sarcasm is totally lost).

These translations are somewhat correct, but they don't capture the manner and style of their Russian origins.

Note that this is a versatile expression, which heavily relies on context. It can be translated by "either... or", "whether ... or", or even "half... half...". Depending on the context you want to use the expression in, I would say that "half... half..." slightly approaches the humorous/sarcastic touch. But it is better if you provide a sample sentence where you would use this expression.

Your second example looks completely different to me. Everything before that seems to be about something that's neither of two possibilities (can't be categorized), but N2 seems to be about something that's definitely one or the other (it's just that the speaker can't decide which applies).

I don't think there's a general formula. I'm sure you could get something sarcastic in specific cases, e.g. using the rule of three to follow two vaguely sensible suggestions with a clearly nonsensical one. In some cases you might be able to mash the words up together to get a kind of compromise/chimera. But it's not at all clear to me or other commenters what the second example is supposed to mean - does it mean the economy hasn't changed at all?

Both words have recently become somewhat pejorative in Russia because they have been overused while the quality of life for the majority of Russians has taken a nosedive. No, the economy hasn't made a breakthrough or a leap, it's been a struggle instead.

Something like “not quite a ⟨…⟩, nor really a ⟨…⟩”?

Were it to adorn just one descriptor, I would have suggested “almost, but not quite entirely unlike ⟨…⟩”

I've seen "not quite ... not really" already and it just doesn't feel right to me.


Он не то геолог, не то археолог ~ "He's some kind of geologist or archaeologist" ("some kind" vs. implied "I'm not sure what his occupation is, could be this or could be that").

"He's some kind of geologist or archaeologist or something like that"
"The Russian economy has made a breakthrough or a leap" (the implied sarcasm is totally lost).
"The Russian economy has made a breakthrough or, as they say (said cynically), "a leap".
The "as they say" implies that this is what the government would say "and nobody believes the government, do they?"
"не то ..., не то ..." is very flexible in Russian, but in English the wording of the translation has to be adapted to the context.

Along similar lines, I think a very good (although highly idiomatic) way to translate this would be "X is an A, or a B, or whatever". And similarly one could say "The economy had made a breakthrough, or a leap, or whatever (they're calling it)." If you're talking, as opposed to writing, you would wave your hand to the side dismissively three times, and roll your eyes. This doesn't just mean you're uncertain which is correct; it strongly conveys that it doesn't matter and that you don't care.

", or whatever" sounds exactly right, thank a lot! Thanks, @JonathanZ

Great. Just be warned that if you make the pronunciation of it too dramatic, i.e. break it into two distinct words and draw out the "r", as in "what - everrrr", you could end up sounding exactly like a teen girl who has had enough of her Mom oh my god already! :-)


neither fish nor fowl (Dictionary.com)
Also, neither fish nor flesh ; neither fish, flesh, nor fowl.
Not one or the other, not something fitting any category under discussion
For example,
They felt he was neither fish nor fowl—not qualified to lead the department, yet not appropriate to work as a staff member either.
This expression appeared in slightly different form in John Heywood's 1546 proverb collection (“Neither fish, nor flesh, nor good red herring”) and is thought to allude to food for monks (fish, because they abstained from meat), for the people (flesh, or meat), and for the poor (red herring, a very cheap fish).

Personally I've always used the form neither fish nor fowl nor good red herring (invariably facetiously), but just the first two (excluded) possibilities is all you need.

I was going to answer this but thought this doesn't quite fit both the examples. It certainly doesn't express sarcasm, does it?

'Neither fish nor fowl' is often used non-pejoratively, as 405 says.. // I've most frequently (and still rarely, especially recently) heard 'neither one thing nor the other' used disparagingly, but can't find a reference for the expression.

@EdwinAshworth: Yes, 'neither one thing nor the other' certainly gets used disparagingly (and non-facetiously) in contexts where if it refers to a person, it could mean something like He's a real Jack-of-all-trades, but master of none.

@user405662: It certainly can express sarcasm - besides being just facetious / "quirky", which is always the case with my ...nor good red herring version.
